# Change date format on DateSigned object - DocuSign C# SDK

Tags: c#, docusignapi

**Using the C# SDK, not the API.**

I want to change to date format from 'MM/dd/YYYY' to 'dd/MM/YY' but I could not find anything similar in the documentation (documentation for the SDK is sparse in general).

DateSigned object:

```
signerDates.Add(new DateSigned
{
    DocumentId = "1", // hard coded, just the one document
    PageNumber = signerPages[i].ToString(), // current page number
    RecipientId = "1", // hard coded, a single recipient 
    XPosition = offsetX, // location 
    YPosition = offsetY 
});
```

If you need more info just comment and I will provide.

Comment: i think that you can use a Culture( fr-FR) to try converting the time format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> documentation for the SDK is sparse in general

Try the new [C# SDK page](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/csharp/) on DocuSign Developer Center.

As for your question, if you use the DateSigned tab (as opposed to using a Text tab) the format is controlled by the account and potentially the singer (if they have an account). This cannot be specified for each tab specifically.
It can be changed for the account, but that will mean all envelopes you sent from that account. If you need different format for different envelopes or tabs - you should use text tab and set it value yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the date setting and made the change, but I never put 2 and 2 together to use tabs.